# Calculating Galois group of $X^{10}-1$ modulo $p$

Tags: galois-theory

Kind of new to Galois theory. I'm interested in computing the galois group of $x^{10}-1$ modulo $p$ for a $p$ a prime number. (let's assume $p$ is not $2$ or $5$).

There are two results that I know of but they seem to contradict eachother:

- By factoring, the $G$ has the same galois group as $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, which I know is irreducible modulo $p$ if and only if $p$ is a generator of $F_5$ (special case of more general result). Thus, if $p$ is a generator of $F_5$, because the roots of  $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ are $a,a^2,a^3,a^4$ for some $a$, $a$ must have degree $4$ in $F_5$, and thus $G$ is $Z/4Z$.
- For any nonzero $a$ in a field $k$, the Galois group over $k$ of the polynomial $X^n-a$ is cyclic, of cardinal $d|n$. By factoring $x^{10}-1$ this would imply its Galois group $G$ is the same as that of $x^{5}-1$, which is thus either the identity or $Z/5Z$. This contradicts the above result.

I am not sure which one is false, but I'm guessing there is an easier way to know the cardinal of $G$?

Comment: The galois group depends over which field we are determining it. Have you chosen the same field in both cases ?

Comment: In the first case I seem to have shown the field must be Z/4Z is $p$ is a generator of $F_5$, however using the second result I show the galois group must always be the identity of Z/5Z. Thus, I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Wait, what? $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ is not a field! I thought that your conclusion was that the Galois group of this polynomial over $\Bbb{F}_p$ is cyclic of order four, when $p$ generates $\Bbb{Z}_5^*$. That is, when $p\equiv2,3\pmod5$.

Comment: Sorry I meant group, not field. My conclusion is exactly that, and furthermore the factorization I had in mind is (X-1)(X+1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)((1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4). Thus the galois group is the same as 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4. Is there an issue with this? If not, it allows me to prove that if $p$ is $2$ or $3$ modulo $5$, the galois group is $Z/4Z$. If $p=4$ mod $5$, it's $Z/2Z$, and if $p$ is 1 mod $5$, identity,

Comment: The cardinality of the Galois group of $x^n-a$ can be as high as $n\phi(n)$. You usually need to adjoin both the $n$th roots of unity as well as an $n$th root of $a$. The possibly first case of this you have encountered is the Galois group of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct about $x^{10}-1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ having the same Galois group (over any field). But $x^n-a$, $a\neq1$, is a different animal altogether.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Ok. To justify my conclusion for $p=1 mod 5$ have used that in this case $P_1$ has a root in $F_p$. I know that for $p=4 mod 5$, $P_1$ factors into 2 irreducible factors. Is this enough to conclude that its Galois group is $Z/2Z$?

Comment: It factoring into two irreducible QUADRATIC factors gives that claim.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes I meant two quadratic factors. I don't see why it is obvious that the claim follows however.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer, I will address your mistakes later below. Let's first ignore $p=2,5$. Then the splitting field $K$ of $x^{10}-1$ is obtained by adjoining a primitive 10th root of unity. Let the degree of $k$ over $\mathbb F_p$ be $r$.

So by Lagrange applied to the multiplicative group, $10$ divides $|K^*| = p^r - 1$. On the other hand, the multiplicative group is cyclic, so by the converse of Lagrange it has an element of order 10 exactly when 10 divides its order.

Putting these together, we see that it splits when $r$ is the smallest integer such that $10$ divides $p^r - 1$, or equivalently the degree of the splitting field is the order of $p$ in $(\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z)^*$.

If $p=2$ then $x^{10} - 1 = (x^5 - 1)^2$ and so you can apply analogous logic to $x^5 - 1$. Likewise if $p=5$ then $x^{10 }- 1 = (x^2 - 1)^5$ and you can go through the same deal (or take advantage of the fact that you just have a quadratic equation).

In your first answer, I don't really follow the factorization, since there are a couple other irreducible factors that you should consider just over $\mathbb Q$, and even then it's not clear how those reduce mod $p$.

Now, as for your second answer, you are making a major (although not uncommon) mistake about the Galois group of $x^n-a$. The result you quote is only true if the ground field contains all of the $n$th roots of unity.

In fact, as we can see above, both of your answers are wrong. One can see that $(\mathbb Z/ 10\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic of order $4$, and so depending on the prime the degree could be 1, 2, or 4 (try $p=11,19,3$, respectively).

Comment: This is correct. But I think you are a bit harsh on the OPs 1st solution. After all, more often than not $p$ is odd, so second roots of unity are automatic, and we really only need the fifth roots of unity to split this completely. Even when $p$ is even, ten vs. five makes no difference (for the reason you explained).

Comment: The same business as over $\Bbb{Q}$, really. When $n$ is odd we have $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well I just said that I don't understand the factorization, and while I agree with you, it's still not clear that the 5th cyclotomic stays irreducible etc. Assuming irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$ is unchanged mod $p$ is not a small mistake, I think. Sorry if it sounded a little too harsh!

Comment: @TokenToucan: In order to justify that r equivalently the degree of the splitting field is the order of p in (Z/10Z)∗, I believe you have implicity used that the splitting field itself is cyclic (well known since the base field is $F_p$)?

Comment: Understood. The question could use a bit of editing to make it clear that in the first version the OP is only looking for the Galois group over a prime field. What you say about the second answer is on the money.

Comment: @galois_dude yes, I need to use the fact that the multiplicative group is cyclic to apply the converse of Lagrange.